# Some questions on node.js development environment and deployment strategy

Tags: node.js, deployment, editor

I'm new to node and reading some books about it. Now I think it's time to do some dev stuff with it. I'm planning to implement a little project which I want to deploy in the cloud (AWS, Heroku, ...).

What I still haven't figured out are following points (I have a MacBook Pro with OS X 10.7):

- which dev environment should I use? I thought about Aptana Studio (no node support as far as I've seen) and transferring the files via ssh to a local VirtualBox CentOS 6.3 machine which has node.js and some modules installed on it
- is there any good deployment strategy for hosting my app in the cloud? For example, if I'm developing with Aptana Studio, I don't think there is a plugin which let's you deploy your code on some virtual server in the AWS or Heroku cloud, isn't it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You can and should develop and run your application locally on your mac. Dealing with 2 machines, 2 OSes, and constant file transfers is a nuisance in development and offers no benefit. It also cripples nice things like fsevents for watching files and good text editor integration.
- If you are into the whole IDE thing, perhaps consider https://c9.io/
- There are several cloud Platform as a Service companies you could consider

  - http://nodejitsu.com/
  - https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs
  - https://www.dotcloud.com/
  - http://www.cloudfoundry.com/
  - http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/nodejs/tutorials/getting-started/
- Here's some blog posts reviewing some of these PaaS offerings

  - http://mrdanadams.com/2012/node-js-paas-hosting-services/
  - http://ocdevel.com/blog/nodejs-paas-comparison
- In terms of deployment, most of these PaaS companies are going to integrate with npm and github, so deployment is going to take no more than a handful of commands at most.

Answer (score 2):

I don't use an IDE per-se. I get by with just Sublime Text for my editor.

The deployment process will depend on where you host your site. I am not sure about Heroku, but with Nodejitsu it's just as simple as running "jitsu deploy" from the terminal and that's it.

If you host the site on your own on a Linux box (i.e. without Heroku or Nodejitsu) you need to account for how to make sure the site restarts after the machine reboots, or after a crash. I wrote about this on my blog. It's doable but somewhat of a chore: http://hectorcorrea.com/blog/running-a-node-js-web-site-in-production-a-beginners-guide

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help!

After doing a lot of research on the topics you've posted, I just wanted to let you know what my setup for developing node applications now looks like:

- Sublime Text 2 Text-Editor with Package Manager and following plugins: git, nodejs, SublimeLinter (BTW: are there some other "essential" plugins you can not live without?)
- iTerm 2 Terminal for all console work (execute node-inspector, ssh to server etc.)
- node.js, npm and additional modules which I want to use for my app

Running everything local on my MacBook Pro. As far as I could test this solution, it seems that it runs very smoothly but most notably: FAST :-)

Regarding node deployment, I take Heroku and nodejitsu into account due to low costs, few administration efforts and features like auto-scaling etc. The only drawback of Heroku is the missing websocket support, which I intend to use natively in my app.

Best regards!